# Передать файл из js в AJAX запросе

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть `input`:

```
<div class="file-upload-link" id="sendWork" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
   label>
     <input type="file" name="sworkfile" id="file">
     <span>Прикрепить файл</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Как с помощью AJAX передать файл на сервер?

Пробовал так, но файл не найден:

```
$('.list-data .file-upload-link#sendWork #file').on('change', function (event, files, label) {
        var file_name = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
        var idwork = $(this).closest(".list-data #sendWork").attr("data-id");
        var token = $(this).closest(".list-data").find("input[type=hidden]").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href+'/send-work',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'idwork' : idwork,
                '_token' : token,
                'wfile' : file_name
            },
            success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил, если кому-то понадобиться

```
 $('.list-data .file-upload-link#sendWork #file').on('change', function (event, files, label) {
            var file_name = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
            var idwork = $(this).closest(".list-data #sendWork").attr("data-id");
            var token = $(this).closest(".list-data").find("input[type=hidden]").val();
            var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('wfile', file_data);
            form_data.append('_token', token);
            form_data.append('idwork', idwork);
            //alert(form_data);
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href+'/send-work',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: function (event, **files, label**) { - ??